# How to get RTSP url from ONVIF supported VMS & Recorder in c#

Tags: c#, onvif

I need to get the RTSP URL from VMS & recorder using ONVIF standard .

Now we get the RTSP url from ONVIF recorder device only using Get stream method using onvif media service , its working perfectly . we get RTSP url based on media profile in onvif . In the onvif return number of media profile from Get profiles method.

1)My doubt is which camera use which media profile ,How to find or relate  this?

2)We get rtsp url only from recorder & we cant get VMS server , How to get rtsp url from VMS server ?